# Empty Arduino memory

Tags: ubuntu, arduino

I am developing for the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) on Linux Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I have uploaded a simple program (from the example stepper) that somehow prevents me from uploading one more time.

I get the following message.

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Is there a way to delete the program that is running on the Arduino? Maybe flushing the flash memory?

PS: I have tried lots of different hard reset / upload combination with no success.

Comment: hey my guess is something went awry with your serial connection rather than the board itself, have you tried a good ol' reboot of the system, my linux skills are lacking to say the least but someone more knowledgeable can probably point you into finer tune diagnostics of the serial ports using something like lspci

Comment: I have a tested the arduino on linux and windows. Got the same problem. I think this is a println in the loop flooding the serial and there now no way for me to over write this programm

Comment: hmm strange I've been toying with the Arduino for quite a while and done certainly plenty of things "wrong" with it but it's been quite resilient to my mistakes.  I think it takes about 8 seconds to boot so during that time you might be able to start uploading the sketch.  Described by JimH here http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1290592824 (I've certainly got in situations where I'm sweating wondering if I just botched my project, persistence has always worked out).

Comment: In a worst case scenario it looks like you're going to need another arduino http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1286408468

Comment: The usb interface initialisation normally resets the Arduino. So the Linux USB was probably mixed up. The 10.04 on my laptop sometimes creates 'dead' USB ports (no connection of drives or Arudino recognised), which go away after a reboot. My Desktop system running 11.04 never had that problem. If you have multiple USB ports and this happens again, try one of the others first before rebooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by using combination of:

1. unplug the USB connection
2. reset (using hard reset button)
3. plug in USB connection
4. upload

Comment: You can get this situation if you flood the serial with messages (with some println in the loop function)